# Use the Cauchy-Riemann equations to show that the function $f(z) = \exp(\bar{z})$ is not analytic everywhere.

Tags: complex-analysis

Use the Cauchy-Riemann equations  to show that the function $f(z) = \exp(\bar{z})$

Here's my attempt:

we have $e^{\bar{z}} = e^{x-iy} = e^{x}e^{-iy} = e^x(\cos(y)-i\sin(y))$

we can then define:

- $u(x,y)= e^x\cos(y)$
- $v(x,y)= -e^x\sin(y)$

Then we can easily see that the Cauchy-Riemann equations aren't satisfied.

What I find weird is that I am asked to show that $f(z)$ is not defined everywhere whereas it's defined almost nowhere.

Is this the right way to go about this problem?

Comment: $f(z)$ is defined everywhere!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we want to find the partial derivative of $u(x, y)$ and $v(x, y)$ with respect to both $x$ and $y$.

$$u_x = e^x \cos(y)$$
$$u_y = -e^x \sin(y)$$
$$v_x = -e^x \sin(y)$$
$$v_y = -e^x \cos(y)$$

The Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied when:

$$v_x = v_y$$
$$v_y = -v_x$$

As you pointed out, these equations are clearly not satisfied. A function $f(z)$ can only be analytic at a point if the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied at that point. If they are not, then the function is not analytic there. Thus, because there are points where $f(z)$ is not analytic, it is not analytic everywhere. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: (it meant everywhere non-analytic instead of non-analytic somewhere)

Comment: Well, if you instead define z conjugate = x - iy, and then take the partial derivatives with respect to that, you get $u_x = 1$ and $v_y = -1$, which is true nowhere.